# PHPUnit & Doctine : How to mock my entities?

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit, symfony-3.4

I'm creating a library with Symfony3.4. And I'm making my tests with PHPUnit.

I've got a method which retrives data from my DB, I have 2 entities which are in a relation, Collection() and CollectionElement() :

```
public function recording()
    {
        try {
            // [...]

            $collection = new Collection();
            $collection->setNomCollection($dbname);

            $collectionExists = $this->em->getRepository(Collection::class)
                ->findOneBy(['nomCollection' => $dbname]);

            // if user provided specific values for $file1, $file2, ... parameters.
            if ((empty($collectionExists)) and (count($datafile) > 0)) {
                // For now, assume USING/OPENING a database is to be done in READ ONLY MODE.
                $this->em->persist($collection);
                $this->em->flush();
            } else {
                $collection = $collectionExists;
            }

            // [....]

            $this->seqcount = count($temp_r);

            foreach($temp_r as $seqid => $line_r) {
                // Check if the file already exists
                $collectionElementExists = $this->em->getRepository(CollectionElement::class)
                    ->findOneBy(['fileName' => $line_r["filename"]]);

                if(empty($collectionElementExists)) {
                    $collectionElement = new CollectionElement();
                    $collectionElement->setIdElement($line_r["id_element"]);
                    $collectionElement->setCollection($collection);
                    $collectionElement->setFileName($line_r["filename"]);
                    $collectionElement->setSeqCount(count($temp_r));
                    $collectionElement->setLineNo($line_r["line_no"]);
                    $collectionElement->setDbFormat($line_r["dbformat"]);

                    $this->em->persist($collectionElement);
                    $this->em->flush();
                }
            }
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            throw new \Exception($e);
        }
    }
```

Then I have to make some tests but I can't manage mocking my EntityManager :

```
    $collection = new Collection();
    $collection->setId(3);
    $collection->setNomCollection("db1");     
    $mockedEm = $this->createMock(EntityManager::class);

 $this->collectionMock = $this->getMockBuilder('AppBundle\Entity\IO\Collection')
            ->setMethods(['findOneBy'])
            ->getMock();
 $this->collectionMock->method("findOneBy")->will($this->returnValue($collection));
```

What can I do to make this work, please ? Furthermore, both entities calls findOneBy() ...

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You correctly mocked the manager with this.

```
$mockedEm = $this->createMock(EntityManager::class);
```

What you missed are the calls to getRepository.

```
$repo = $this->createMock(EntityRepository::class);
$mockedEm->expects($this->once())->method('getRepository')->with(CollectionElement::class)->willReturn($repo);
```

After that you can have expectations for the findOneBy on the repository.

```
$repo->expects($this->exactly(2))->method('findOneBy')
  ->withConsecutive(['fileName' => 'f1'], ['fileName' => 'f2'])
  ->willReturnOnConsecutiveCalls($entity1, $entity2);
```

Comment: I have 2 repos, then I do it like that ?


$mockedEm = $this->createMock(EntityManager::class);

$repo = $this->createMock(EntityRepository::class);
        $mockedEm->expects($this->once())->method('getRepository')->with(CollectionElement::class)->willReturn($repo);

        $repo2 = $this->createMock(EntityRepository::class);
        $mockedEm->expects($this->once())->method('getRepository')->with(Collection::class)->willReturn($repo2);

Comment: Exception : Expectation failed for method name is equal to 'getRepository' when invoked 1 time(s) :(

Comment: Be aware, I got 2 repos = Collection and CollectionElement

Comment: That's why I added an example for two different calls on the same method. This is a template, which should point you in the right directions, not the exact code you need.

Comment: Well, I don't know what I'm doing bad, and I learn by the examples ...

Comment: Okay, after some editing, I can execute my test, thanks.